# How to declare variable depends on other variable as a constraint in AMPL?

Tags: ampl

How to declare variable depends on other variable as a constraint in AMPL?

I'm trying to solve the minimize the difference between "maximum number of variable - minimum number of variable"

So, my objective equation is
minimize max{t in 0..T}production[t] + min{t in 0..T}production[t];
(t is index and T is time periods parameter and production is decision variable.)

However, it is not linear algebra.
Thus, I'm trying to declare 'max{t in 0..T} production[t]' as a variable 'y'.
So, I would like to write 'var y >= all production'.
But it's not working.

Comment: subject to const2{i in 1..T}: z <= production[i];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint

```
s.t. max_production{t in 0..T}: y >= production[t];
```

will ensure that `y` is greater or equal than `production[t]` for all `t in 0..T`. If you minimize `y` then it will be exactly `max{t in 0..T} production[t]`.